# Re-labeling one axis on a dual-axis chart

Tags: r

I have a chart which shows lap position progression over a 2 lap race from starting position to end position.

I would like to amend the chart to have the drivers name on the left y-axis, which aligns with their starting position (i.e from top to bottom, the names would read bill, who started first, maria, who started second, and claudio, who started third) and their end position number would be on the right side (from top to bottom, first to third)

I have been working on this for a while but can't figure it out. Also, as shown, I'd like the chart to go from 1 at the top to 3 at the bottom, but I can't get rid of the negative for some reason. Many thanks for anybody that can help:

```
## reprex
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
dat <- data.frame(name = c(rep("bill", 3), rep("maria", 3), rep("claudio", 3)),
                  lap = rep(0:2, 3),
                  pos = c(1, 1, 2, 
                          2, 3, 1,
                          3, 2, 3))

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = lap, y = -pos, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(3),
                     sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(3))
```

Desired end result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can label the primary axis using a labeller function that finds which driver was at each position on lap 0, and add a `sec_axis` instead of a `dup_axis`.

You can also use `scale_y_reverse` rather than using `-pos` to order the axis correctly:

```r
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = lap, y = pos, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 1:3,
                  labels = function(x) {
                    dat$name[dat$lap == 0][order(dat$pos[dat$lap == 0])][x]
                    },
                  sec.axis = sec_axis(function(x) x, 
                                      breaks = 1:3, labels = label_ordinal())) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(3))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Allan - thank you for the help. One quick follow-up, do you know if there is an easy way to make 1, 2, 3 appear as 1st, 2nd, and 3rd?

Answer (score 1):

You could also stick with your `-pos` to reorder your y-axis and then simply reorder the breaks and labels the same way. Less elegant than Allan Cameron solution, though.

Cheers

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = lap, y = -as.numeric(pos), color = Driver, group = Driver)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = F) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Driver",
                     breaks = -(1:nlevels(dat$Driver)),
                     labels = unique(dat$Driver),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.,
                                         name = "End Position",
                                         breaks = -(1:length(levels(as.factor(dat$pos)))),
                                         labels = levels(as.factor(dat$pos))))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(3))
```

[image]